# Spring @PreAthorize causes NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I’m using Spring MVC to create a web app. I’m trying to use @PreAuthorize in order to restrict certain actions to specific roles. Nevertheless, if I include this annotation in my code I get “Error creating bean: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable”. This happens disregarding where I put this annotation or what I set it to. Can anyone tell me please what's wrong?

Dao:

```
@Repository
public interface AnswerDao extends CrudRepository<Answer, Long>  {

    Answer findOne(Long id);

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    void delete(Long id);
}
```

Service:

```
public interface AnswerService {

    Answer findOne(Long id);
    void save(Answer answer);
    void delete(Answer answer);
}
```

ServiceImp:

```
@Service
public class AnswerServiceImp implements AnswerService {

    @Autowired
    private AnswerDao answerDao;

    @Override
    public Answer findOne(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return answerDao.findOne(id);
    }

        @Override
        public void save(Answer answer) {
            answerDao.save(answer);

        }

        @Override
        public void delete(Answer answer) {
            answerDao.delete(answer);

        }

}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    //@Autowired 
    //public AnswerDao answerDao;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
        .passwordEncoder(User.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf();
    }

    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
        return (request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/");
    }
```

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class AskSpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AskSpringApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.askSpring</groupId>
    <artifactId>askSpring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>askSpring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0.M11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: well, it's a missing aspectjweaver dependency (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725901/spring-autowire-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror). but that doesn't explain why the spring-boot-starter-security isn't pulling in that dependency for itself - spring security clearly seems to need it for the annotation to work.

Comment: After I included aspectjweaver the application doesn't throw an error anymore, but the @PreAuthorize doesnt seem to be doing anything, it's completely ignored regardless what it is trying to check.                                  Edit: I moved it to Service interface and it works fine now, thanks a lot for help.

Comment: try moving the `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` annotation to be on the `AnswerServiceImp.delete` method, rather than on the DAO interface method.  I don't think annotations get inherited from an interface to a concrete class.  And, in a layering sense, it's normally your Service layer where you do the authorisation checks, rather than the DAO layer anyway.